# How to make time restriction (limit) in android game?

Tags: android, time

I'm making one application where user needs to do some task while time is passing. How I was thinking of doing it is:

show task to user -> start counting seconds -> if task is not solved within certain seconds, application writes: "You failed".

I have only one solution in my head, since I didn't come across same till now -
show task to used and start thread with counting seconds and waiting, something like:

```
sleep(1000);
secondsCounter++;
if (secondsCounter => LIMIT){
    write("You failed!");
}
```

Still, something tells me that this is not proper way of solving it. Is there other (better) way?

Comment: You could run your timer as an asynctask so u do not have to worry about managing threads because it does it in background for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a handler for this:

```
// set this to true if user succeeds before time runs out.
boolean userSucceeded = false;

new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        if (!userSucceeded) {
            // write("you failed")
        }
    }
}, 1000L); // 1 second
```